# How to shim npm package dependency in browserify?

Tags: node.js, npm, browserify, browserify-shim

So I have a React project, in which I'm actually deploying with react-lite as the footprint is *much* smaller. I'd like to use [react-nouislider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-nouislider), but in it's package.json, I've found this:

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^0.14.0"
}
```

What this means is that whenever I require react-nouislider, it pulls in React instead of react-lite. How do I shim dependencies of an npm package from my top-level package.json?

This is how I'm shimming react-lite in:

```
"browser": {
    "react": "react-lite"
}
```

And I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
"browserify-shim":{
    "react-nouislider": {
        "depends": "react-lite"
    }
}
```

**How is it possible to shim a dependency of a package itself?**

Answer (score 0):

Browserify Shim's tagline is:

> Makes CommonJS incompatible files browserifyable.

Your issue here is that `react-lite` is already CommonJS compatible. For any CommonJS compatible file, Browserify will automatically add its `dependencies` and `peerDependencies` as appropriate, before Browserify Shim gets involved.

I suggest you change the `peerDependencies` entry in the `react-nouislider` package to the appropriate version of `react-lite` and remove your Browserify Shim config above as it's no longer needed. When you do this, be sure to run any tests in the `react-nouislider` package to make sure it still works with `react-lite` instead of React. A good way of doing this is forking `react-nouislider` to your own repo, making the change there, and pulling from that repo in your `package.json`.

Comment: No, this doesn't work. The nouislider package is still importing React.

Comment: Thanks, but `I suggest you change the peerDependencies entry in the react-nouislider package` defeats the entire purpose of npm packages

Comment: @JohnDoe that's a good point. One might use `react-lite` as a stripped-down version of React for super-fast load times...but sacrificing a lot of the capabilities of React. One of these capabilities would be to use supporting packages without forking them to create a version tailored for `react-lite`.

Comment: @JohnDoe one more suggestion - try doing my previous answer but setting `"browser": {"react": false}`

Comment: @JohnDoe sorry - check this from the docs: > The browser field only applies to the current package. Any mappings you put will not propagate down to its dependencies or up to its dependents. This isolation is designed to protect modules from each other so that when you require a module you won't need to worry about any system-wide effects it might have. Likewise, you shouldn't need to wory about how your local configuration might adversely affect modules far away deep into your dependency graph.

Comment: @JohnDoe one more hacky way might be to create two separate bundles. The first imports your config except for `react-uislider` and adds `react-lite` to your `window` variable as `window.React`. Then, in your second bundle, you could use [browserify-global-shim](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-global-shim) and pull in React (which is already shimmed as `react-lite`) as the dependency for `react-uislider`.